# Problem in applying active class to wordpress menu

Tags: menus

I am learning wordpress by my own and this is the code of html template.

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">Who we are</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="causes.html" class="nav-link">Causes</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">Stories</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to convert it into wordpress. I converted it into wordpress by adding this code:-

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu' => 'primary', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse', 'container_id' => 'ftco-nav', 'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav ml-auto', 'menu_id' => '', ));?>
```

but the problem is that how will I apply active class to it? please someone help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

Change your active class name in your css. WordPress adds the following active classes, depending on the context of the active state:

`current-menu-item`, `current-menu-ancestor`, `current-menu-parent`, and `current-page-ancestor`

Answer (score 0):

May be this can helps you. add in functions.php

```
function add_active_class_to_menu_item($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'add_active_class_to_menu_item' , 10 , 2);
```